# MathJax accents in Safari 10.1

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

Tilde accents, such as $\tilde g$ (typed as `\tilde g`), seem to be displaying bizarrely, with the tilde to the right of, rather than on top of, the accented symbol, and with the following kerning messed up (so that there appears to be no space between $\tilde g$ and the following parenthesis above, and just here).  Although I cannot say for sure, I seem to remember that this was not always the case.  Has something changed?

Extra information (thanks to [@JonEricson](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3207/has-the-font-rendering-for-the-tilde-accent-changed#comment14241_3207) for prompting, to [@Glorfindel](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3207/has-the-font-rendering-for-the-tilde-accent-changed#comment14243_3207) for reproducing and instructions on how to post the screenshot, and to [@DavideCervone](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3207/accents-in-safari-10-1#comment14245_3207) for suggesting to check the Math Renderer):  I am using Safari 10.1 on macOS 10.12.14, with HTML-CSS as my Math Renderer.  Screenshot below.
[image: Screenshot of misrendered accent]]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot, the browser/OS you are using and whether you have any user scripts installed? I'm not seeing a problem with the tilde in this question.

Comment: @JonEricson, I am using Safari 10.1 on macOS 10.12.4.  The display issue persists with extensions disabled.  I just checked, and the problem doesn't occur on Firefox.  How do I attach a screenshot to a post / comment?

Comment: Repro'd in Safari on macOS (same versions as LSpice): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YWfM.png It probably has something to do with [MathJax now being hosted on CloudFlare](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294710/295232).

Comment: @LSpice when you [edit] your question, there's a toolbar above the box where you enter your content. The sixth button inserts an image for you; you can also press Ctrl + G.

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to the CDN change.  A recent change in WebKit has affects some accents in Safari, so it is more likely that it is [this issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1709) than the change in cdn.  The fact that it only seems to affect Safari suggests this is likely the case.  Are you using CommonHTML output?

Comment: @DavideCervone, I don't know how to find out whether I am using the CommonHTML output.

Comment: Use the contextual menu (control-click) on some typeset math and you should see the MathJax menu.  Use `Math Settings` then `Math Renderer` to see which one is selected.  Try changing to a different one and see if that helps (the SVG output would probably work for you).

Comment: @DavideCervone, thanks.  The problem seems only to occur with HTML-CSS output.  I can make the change on a formula-by-formula level, but is there a way to change it globally?

Comment: @LSpice, the MathJax menu settings are site-wide, not equation-by-equation, so if you set it once, it should work everywhere on that site.  You do have to set it for each site, however, and the setting is stored in a cookie, so if you have those turned off or restricted, that could affect it as well.

Comment: This was re-tagged 'status-completed', and I cannot remove the tag, but the problem persists for me.

Comment: I still have this problem in Safari on iOS. Is anyone aware of a way to switch the renderer on iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was introduced in the upgrade from Safari 10.0.3 (OSX 10.12.3) to Safari 10.1 (OSX 10.12.4), so I would think it unrelated to the switch in MathJax hosting. It seems to be an issue with the WebKit that Safari uses, but not other browsers.

[image]

*Screenshots directly before and after the Safari upgrade on April 15.*

Comment: Math renderer HTML-CSS has this problem, but none of the other renderers.

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it down. I've opened https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1737 to track this but we generally advise using the CommonHTML output.

Comment: 2.7.2 (with a fix) is now in beta, cf. also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26768/mathjax-v2-7-2-beta

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in [MathJax v2.7.2](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-7-2-now-available/) that we switched to network-wide earlier today.